# Can we do gayathri mantram instead of sandhyavandanam?

Tags: dharma-shastras, gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam

Can we do Gayathri Mantram instead of sandhya-vandanam?

If yes, May I know how many times does the Mantram need to be chanted?

Answer (score 1):

Sandhyavandanam is a procedure to invoke the ultimate prowess in you by chanting various mantras & doing things like arghya samarpana with the main focus on Maa Gayatri

Chanting the Gayatri mantra alone comes under technical aspect & it's a personal experience of anyone to concentrate on the form of god

According to Scriptures, those who get upanayana samskaram & wear the jandhyam(holy thread), should definitely perform the sandhyavandanam at the very minimum of one time per day..(Generally 3 times per day)..

There are minor restrictions under which the sandhyavandanam to be not done, However in the procedure, generally the Gayatri mantra is chanted 108 times

Comment: It would be more useful if some sources are cited especially for 2nd and 4th paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

It is better do Sandhyavndhanm than gayatri mantram because Gayatri mantram is in sandhyavndhanam. Plus you do more prayers to different gods Whereas gayatri mantram is only for the sun or Maa Gayatri. When you do upanynam it means that you will do sandhyavandhanm every day.